# Installing gopkg.in/yaml.v2 from local file (Go)

Tags: go, yaml

I am trying to build a Go file for a tool that I want to install but I am getting the following error :

```
pgwatch2.go:26:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/postgres/go/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from $GOPATH)"gopkg.in/yaml.v2" in any of:
```

I realized that I need to get the Go module gopkg.in/yaml.v2 but my server lacks internet access. Therefore, I tried 2 solution that did not help me :

1) Yum install golang-gopkg-yaml-devel-v2.noarch

2) I downloaded the source files (yaml-2.2.1.zip) and put them in the server but I do not know how to continue from here. How I install the yaml? I tried to unzip and use go install into my desired directory.
Here is the error I received.

```
go install: no install location for directory /PostgreSQL/pgwatch2/pgwatch2-master/pgwatch2/yaml-2.2.1 outside GOPATH
    For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

Can somebody give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want your server to be accessible from the internet, then you can add a new instance which is on public subnet and then create a nat server in that instance and connect your server to that nat instance so that the server can download from the internet, but it wont be accessible from the internet via a public ip.

Install via go get

```
go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2
```

and make sure you have GOPATH set, if not

make modifications in .bashrc(linux) to add the following line.

```
export GOPATH=<path>
```

## Update

If you dont want to try out the above method you can try this.

Extract the contents of `yaml-2.2.1.zip` to `GOPATH/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2`.
This should work, but this can be tiring if you have lots of packages.

Comment: go get tries to acess the internet. I dont have access to the internet from the server..

Comment: first make sure you have `GOPATH` set.
you can check via `echo $GOPATH`. then extract the contents of yaml-2.2.1.zip to `GOPATH/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2`